# Is there a way to #if Objective-C++?

Tags: c++, objective-c, macros, llvm, objective-c++

I am well aware of the `#if __OBJC__` macro, but I was wondering if there was an equivalent thing for ObjC++?

Comment: Well, there's a standard define for C++, and it should be set for Objective-C++.  (I don't offhand recall what it is, though.)

Comment: Seems like you can `&&` the macros for Obj-C and C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The macro for C++ is `__cplusplus`, to check for both Objective-C and C++ use

```
#if __OBJC__ && __cplusplus
```